# XMLHttprequest within Mocha on Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest, mocha.js

I am trying to use [node-xmlhttprequest](https://github.com/driverdan/node-XMLHttpRequest). So if I do like this

```
// f.js
(function()
   XMLHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest
   xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
   xhr.open('GET', "http://url-bla-bla.json", true)
   xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
      console.log("xhr "+JSON.stringify(xhr))
   }
   xhr.send()
)()
```

and call it `node f` (assuming `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is not an issue for `http://url-bla-bla.json` link - it works

but If I try it to wrap the same thing into Mocha spec

```
describe('foo',function(){
  it('xhr test',function(){
    XMLHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.open('GET', "http://url-bla-bla.json", true)
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
      console.log("xhr "+JSON.stringify(xhr))
    }
    xhr.send()
  } 
}
```

and run with `mocha f` (I don't even have to wrap it in Mocha spec)

it won't work and fail with `readyState == 1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an asynchronous operation. In Mocha, you have to use the `done` callback to get the test to complete when the operation is complete, like this:

```
describe('foo',function(){
  it('xhr test',function(done){
    XMLHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.open('GET', "http://url-bla-bla.json", true)
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
      console.log("xhr "+JSON.stringify(xhr))
      if (xhr.readyState === 4)
          done();
    }
    xhr.send()
  });
});
```

Besides fixing syntax errors, the only other changes are adding the `done` argument to the callback to the `it` call and calling `done()` when `onreadystatechanges` executes and the `readyState` has reached `4`.

Comment: @louis , I am using similar kind of test. My problem is xhr request for http protocol works file but for https it shows timeout exceeded.

Comment: @ArjunNayak `https` should make no difference, so long as the server is passing a certificate that has no security issues. If it does have security issues (e.g. a self-signed certificate), I think it will error and you have to listen for that. If you're still having trouble, you should ask a new question detailing exactly what you are doing and what the security setup is (are you using a valid certificate, for instance?)

Comment: Thank you for reply. Yes you are right. https should not make any difference. The problem was that server was sending ssl certificate created using letsencrypt which is expired. I will need to renew the certificate. May be something wrong with the cron job I created to renew ssl certificate.

Comment: Where is `done()` defined, and what does it look like?